# Select some of the elements by name?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

For example, the XML of

```
<X>
  <A>aaa</A>
  <B>bbb</B>
  <C>ccc</C>
</X>
```

How to select the item A and C in one XPATH?

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(x);
var r = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/X/(A, C)"); // r should have aaa and ccc only
```

`(xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("/X/*[local-name() = \"A\" or local-name() = \"C\"]")).OuterXml` returns `<A>aaa</A>`?

Comment: Could you please clarify how do you expect "should have aaa and ccc" to be represented? (It looks like you hope to get two nodes selected as one... which is strange and I'm not even sure is possible. Clarification why selecting multiple nodes does not work would be helpful)

Comment: Note that the path expression `/X/(A, C)` is valid since XPath 2.0, but you appear to be using a Microsoft implemention of XPath that only supports the ancient XPath 1.0 standard.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var r = xdoc.SelectNodes("//X/C | //X/A");
```

---

```
var xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.LoadXml(x);
var r = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//X/C | //X/A");

foreach (XmlNode i in r)
    Debug.WriteLine(i.Value);
```

Comment: I actually used XPath evaluator. I didnt see that he used SelectSingleNode. the difference is I could not validate OP's query

Answer (score 1):

This one XPath,

```
/X/*[self::A or self::C]
```

will select all `A` and `C` children of `X`.

Note that since you seek to select multiple elements, you'll want to use [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`, with example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes?view=netframework-4.7.2) rather than `.SelectSingleNode()` and be prepared to process the `XmlNodeList` that it returns.